# After Effects: How do I achieve collapsing transform using nested CC Cylinder Effect?

Tags: after-effects, cc

I am just preparing for a new project where I am going to need a lot of cylinder-shapish layers reacting to my 3d moving camera. In order to have eveerything organised I am using precomps to nest seperate elements.

Usually by activating "collapsing transforms" (further explained here: http://www.digitalsandwich.net/portfolio/ae-quicktip-collapse-transformations/) I can have one master Camera in my outer composition and have all elements reacting to it accordingly. But somehow, using the cc cylinder effect in precomps, it messes up.

Does anyone know why? Or have a workarround?

Thanks in Advance
Marten

Comment: I am not at my editing pc right now so just a guess: are you maybe expecting the cylinders to be 3d while in reality they are not? Without understanding completely what you are trying to achieve, for me it sounds like you might need a "real" 3d software like blender, or at least use the cinema 4d plug-in of after effects. Most objects of afx internal plug-ins are not real 3d objects. But maybe you can post a screenshot of how it's messed up and approx describe how it is supposed to look.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think CC cylinder create true 3D objects, they are really just flat 2D planes with 3D shaded shapes on them.  I think Hans' suggestion of creating 3D shapes in Cinema4D (a basic version ships with AE CC 2015) is probably the way to go.

Comment: Not sure what version they added the Cinema 4D and Raytrace renderers in After Effects, but I think they are the only way to collapse a curved surface.